# Android App Server

Tags: android

I've done some searching however I haven't really found anything as general as what I'm looking for.  I have an idea for an app and all I know is that I will need a server.  My plan is to "lease" space on the server for my clients to update their information.  Then, it will allow other app users to view their information both on the app and I want to push out a web app/interface.  Where do I start as far as server space. Do I implement my own, what kind of expenses will I need for that? Do I buy space available from a host? Is my idea feasible at that?

Answer (score 2):

Look for a "virtual server" rent.
Typical prices are around $10/mo for a Single Core + 512Mb RAM + 20Gb HDD

Amazon EC2 allows you to pay by-hour and by-gigabyte basis, but will be more expensive in total $/mo.
They have a free period around 6 months AFAIR for tiny instances.